# FastAPI backend and Streamlit frontend on Docker: Max retries exceeded with URL

Tags: docker, containers, fastapi, streamlit

**NOTE**: I'm developing on MacOS.

I'm new to web-development and containerisation, so excuse my lack of nomenclature.

Below is a overview of my system. I'm working on my local machine with two containers running, one for the frontend exposing port 8501 (8501 enforced by streamlit) to local 8081, and one for the backend exposing port 80 to local 8000 (fastapi).

[system diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhQjP.png)

[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDWHe.png)

My frontend makes calls to my api via `http://127.0.0.1:8000/...` but is getting:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /blogs/all (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0xffff6d6a6e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I can verify that my backend is working as expected, going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs/all` on my browser works without any issues.

I think the issue might be that my frontend container isn't directly calling my backend container port, instead its trying to route through my local 8000 port?

I've tried changing the request URL in my frontend app from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs/all` to `http://localhost:8000/blogs/all` and `http://<backend ip>:8000/blogs/all` but this didn't work.

I would really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: Can you please share some code?  eg) the dockerfile you're using

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the solution, please see solution section in the question above. Code can be found here: https://github.com/RamonJWS/fast-api-blog/tree/dev (its just a simple learning project) @Doracahl

Comment: you did not upload a solution.